# X86: Frequency or architecture or other factor matter to compute fast and massive python/numpy loops?

Tags: cpu, python

We need to compute numpy/python script that run for days because they use a massive number of loops to compute small Numpy/Python float arrays (array of some Mo). Operations are over rows taken one by one, then lines by lines, etc.

I was surprised to find a AMD APU A10-5700 @ 3.4 is faster (around 25%) than a Xeon X5650 @ 2.7 ghz to compute that kind of scripts. The speed is proportional to cpu frequencies ratio.

What kind of cpu properties matter to compute that kind of script? Do I have to only favour CPU with high frequency for that kind of task? 
Thanks for incoming answer.

edit: operation over arrays are yet parallelized using pp but no GPGPU (as opencl). So my question applies on a single thread per cpu unit.

Comment: Xeon and more generally server cpu acheive better performance using as many cores as possible instead of attempting to make each core fast. I don’t now why but yes, you’ll always get faster single thread performance with cpu targeting the consumer market https://superuser.com/q/1496330

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using a multi-threaded approach to your python script, then any CPU with faster clock and single threaded performance will end up doing much better then a CPU designed around applications using multiple threads with slower single thread performance.

The best way to probably get better performance is to re-write the python script to take advantage of multiple threads if possible(watch out for concurrency).  Otherwise look for CPU's that have very high single thread performance

Comment: Sigh ! Python as a Gil. So while it has multithreads it runs single threaded.

Answer (score 0):

It's more *how the script is written* - if it isn't in any way parallel, then having many cores isn't going to help, and you're merely pushing the same instructions through at differing clock speeds. If you could find a way to divide the load across the logical processors, the more multi-core processor architecture stands a better chance.

Comment: indeed, i edited. The code is yet multi-threaded. I was just looking at "per thread" performance, if I have to buy the cpu with more cores and fastest frequency only, or if i need to look for other properties.

Comment: Well, there is other stuff to do with whether the data & code fit in the relevant on-chip caches, but in general, you can more easily improve performance by adjusting the algorithm in use, rather than throwing more/faster hardware at it.

Comment: @RowlandShaw by design, python run multithreaded programs in single thread mode (the Gil).